# Reproducible results with Keras with Tensorflow background

Tags: tensorflow, keras, deep-learning, binary-reproducibility

I have my own network. But it is giving me different outputs each time I run the code.  I'm using keras (with Tensorflow backend), write the following code for reproducibility. My training sample: 280, validation sample # 27, test sample # 21.

```
# The following  lines are for reproducibility
import os
import random as rn
os.environ['PYTHONHASHSEED'] = '0'
# random seed for NP genreator of ranodm numbers
np.random.seed(37) 
rn.seed(1254)      # specifying the seed for python-generated random     numbers:

import tensorflow as tf
tf.compat.v1.set_random_seed(89)    #tf.set_random_seed(89)

import keras.backend.tensorflow_backend as K
session_conf =  tf.compat.v1.ConfigProto(intra_op_parallelism_threads=1,    inter_op_parallelism_threads=1)
sess=tf.compat.v1.Session(graph=tf.compat.v1.get_default_graph(),    config= session_conf)
 K.set_session(sess)
```

Comment: Theano or Tensorflow?

Comment: Sorry, tensorflow it is.

Comment: It's probably a problem with your version. An update could solve it, I think. This used to happen in a certain version (not sure it's your problem, but since you set so many seeds and it's still bad....)